# adding a column into a postgres table throws no viable alternative at input using jdbc

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

i am trying to add a column to an existing table using jdbc, here is my code:

```
Dataset<Row> sql_statment1 =
                spark.sql("ALTER TABLE class "

                        + "ADD student_id INT NULL "
                        + "CONSTRAINT colstudent_Null DEFAULT '1' ");
```

it return this error :

```
no viable alternative at input 'ALTER TABLE class ADD student_id'(line 1, pos 27)
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Try `ALTER TABLE class ADD student_id INT NULL DEFAULT 1`.

Comment: It is probably not the cause of the error, but the name of the constraint must be *before* the constraint (or otherwise, your naming convention for a `default` is a bit off). However, I don't think spark can execute DDL like this (as this seems to be intended for executing queries).

Comment: i have tried it but it didnt work for me same error